# How Can I Improve Application Performance When Add Thousands of Child Control in Container?

Tags: c#, combobox, user-controls, windows-forms-core

I created a custom ComboBox with following elements:

1. ComboBoxItem: Consist of A) PicttureBox to show image for each item B) Label to show item text. Both control located in UserControl to create ComboBoxItem.
2. ComboBox: when user click on DownArrow, the following steps occure: 1) Create an instance of Form 2) Create an instance of FlowLayoutPanel 3) In a foreach statement, for each item I create an instance of ComboBoxItem then add to FlowLayoutPanel.

Problem : For 50 to 100 items everything is ok, but more than 100 or 200, my ComboBox open items with delay and scrolling items is done slowly. How can I improve performance in my custom ComboBox to load more items?

thank you all

Comment: What's the filesize of your pictures? do you have an optimized resolution?

have you looked into assemble the list before adding it and then use the addrange to add all at once? sometimes windows forms repaints after an add which we don't need while adding

Comment: With Windows Forms, slow response means you are refreshing the View after each item is added instead of waiting until all the items are added.  Without seeing code I cannot determine why this is happening.

Comment: The size of image is 1 KB. I didn't add items as a range but it was one by one. I try you suggestion. I do steps in code then finally Show the Form. Dose Windows From Controls call OnPaint function before showing controls to user?

Comment: As a final solution, I used SuspendLayout() of FlowLayoutPanel control and after adding all 500 ComboBoxItems, I called ResumeLayout(). It caused delay decreases from 11 seconds to 3 seconds.